# Load Multiple Image on Jupyter Notebook python

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm on thesis working on PCA. i want to use my own datasets. but now i stuck, i can't load the image to my dataFrame or array. can anyone explain me how to do it.
I had already test out load image `Image from PIL`. or `imread from matplotlib`, maybe i made some mistake, or else, because i'm still new in this python programming.

```
faces = []
for file in glob.glob('D:/ML/sample/LEFT/*.JPG'):
    image = cv2.imread(file,0)
    face = pd.Series(image.flatten(), name=file)
    faces.append(face)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
faces_pca = PCA(n_components=0.8)
faces_pca.fit(faces)
```

I tried, as simple code above but it not works. please help.

Comment: What isn’t working, what happens?

Comment: jpg image cannot directly append to array. finally found out how to solve. i'm on working on simply my code to share.

Comment: _i'm on working on simply my code to share._ To write an answer?

Comment: yeah. but still need to optimize it for general use. and a little bit documentation, i'll share then.